# Does a Java interface work different in Spring Boot? -- Is this Spring Wizardry or do I just not understand interfaces?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I'm working on an application that uses Spring Boot. In it, an interface is used in a way that I don't understand. 
I've stripped down the code to the only parts that I think are relevant to the question.

1. A controller object is created.
2. It is told to process some stuff.
3. The controller tells an interface processor to do the work.
4. There is a processor that implements the interface processor.

It was my understanding that when using an interface you'd do something like: `IProcessor iProcessor = new Processor();`
In other words, assigning the interface an implementation. But in this sample program it seems the processor implementation is implicitly assigned, not in the code as far as I can tell. I'm trying to figure out if this is some Spring wizardry or if I'm just understanding interfaces wrong. There are four files that I have put in order of application flow.

```
@Component
public class DoStuff {
    private ProcessorController PROCESSOR_CONTROLLER;
    private OtherLayer OTHER_LAYER;

    @Autowired
    public DoStuff(ProcessorController processorController, OtherLayer otherLayer) {
        this.PROCESSOR_CONTROLLER = processorController;
        this.OTHER_LAYER = otherLayer;
    }

    public void execute() {
        List<String> stuffToProcess = OTHER_LAYER.getStuffToProcess();
        PsROCESSOR_CONTROLLER.process(stuffToProcess);
    }
}

@Component
public class ProcessorController {
    private final IProcessor IPROCESSOR;

    @Autowired
    public ProcessorController(IProcessor iProcessor) {
        this.IPROCESSOR = iProcessor;
    }

    public void process(List<String> stuffToProcess) {
        stuffToProcess.forEach(t -> IPROCESSOR.process(t))
    }
}

public interface IProcessor {
    void process(String stuff);
}

@Component
public class Processor implements IProcessor {

    @Override
    public void process(String stuff) {
        System.out.println(stuff);
    }
}
```

If the ProcessorController class contained something like this:
So part of the ProcessorController class would look like this instead:

```
private final IProcessor IPROCESSOR;

@Autowired
public ProcessorController(Processor Processor) {
    this.IPROCESSOR = processor;
}
```

I think it would make sense since we've linked the interface with its implementation. But it isn't that way. So what is going on here?

Comment: All looks okay. Try this instead (for your Processor): @Service public class Processor implements IProcessor. More information here - https://javarevisited.blogspot.com/2017/11/difference-between-component-service.html and https://javarevisited.blogspot.com/2017/11/difference-between-component-service.html. Didnt get a chance to try your code. But using Service annotation is worth a shot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Your understanding is correct**

```
IProcessor iProcessor = new Processor();
```

The above way is correct way to assigning the implementation to Interface reference variable.This phenomena is known as loose coupling .Because if the method parameter type is of interface then it can be bind with multiple implementation based on requirement .

For Example we have

interface Test and Test1 and Test2 are its implementation classes
Then void method(Test test)

so now this method can bind with both Test1 and Test2 like method(Test1 obj) and method(Test2 obj)

But your controller is tightly coupled here not loosely coupled.Because Your constructor call is bind with Implementation class reference not interface.And if your project need tight coupling then there is no use to create class refrence of interface type rather you can create `private final Processor PROCESSOR;` instead of below code

```
private final IProcessor IPROCESSOR;

@Autowired
public ProcessorController(Processor Processor) {
    this.IPROCESSOR = processor;
}
```

It should be like

```
@Autowired
private final IProcessor IPROCESSOR;
```

or

```
private final IProcessor IPROCESSOR;

@Autowired
public ProcessorController(IProcessor Processor) {
    this.IPROCESSOR = processor;
}
```